# Autowired return NPE

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I tried to do automation testing usign @ Autowired annotation but the beans that annotated with @autowired is null and cause NPE. What wrong with my code?

```java
@ComponentScan({"com.nicholas.pages.LoginPages", "com.nicholas.utils.Methods"})
public abstract class TestManager {

    protected ExtentTest extentTest;

    @Autowired
    protected LoginPages loginPages;
}
```

```
@Test // This is a class of GenericTestManager
public void testLogin() {
    extentTest = extentManager.getExtentReports().createTest("Test 1");

    loginPages.login();
}
```

```
@Component
public class LoginPages {

    @Autowired
    private Methods methods;

    public void login() {
        methods.waitUntilPageIsReady();

    }
}
```

I have other variable need to instantiate manually cause it using Singleton design pattern.

[Source Code](https://github.com/nicholaswkc34/Selenium-V4-Selenide)

Comment: I am unable to open the github link. For your code I have questions
Which is the concrete class for TestManager. ComponentScan?
Should Component Scan should have a path to folder and not class file?

Comment: Try git clone https://github.com/nicholaswkc34/Selenium-V4-Selenide.git.  TestManager is abstract class. No idea how to use Componentscan though..

Comment: What is your email address i will send you the source code?

Comment: It could be an access issue. Give me access on my github user 
https://github.com/CodeWarOdin